# how to launch existing project with web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I am an LAMP(JS) journeyman dev.

I have been asked to help on a project built with web2py? NOTE: I have next to no xp in py

I cloned the project on my box and downloaded web2py -> followed the instructions on the official site to start the server.

How do I launch the existing project?

When I direct the browser that web2py starts to the index file it shows all the py code and no styling.

this is what I see in the browser:

```
{{include 'web2py_ajax.html'}}
­
logo

    Home »
    Members »
    Groups »
    {{if auth.has_membership('Admins'):}}
    Admin »
    {{pass}}
    About Us »
    Account » {{='auth' in globals() and custom.navbar(auth.navbar(mode='bare')) or ''}}

{{include}}
```

I will be doing some jQuery / CSS work on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be navigating directly to the index file on the filesystem. Rather, you should go to the URL exposed by the web2py router. If you are running locally, it would be `http://localhost:8000/myapp/default/index`. Probably, though, you're going to need to read some of the [documentation](http://web2py.com/book) to understand how things work. In particular, check out the section on [dispatching](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/04/the-core#Dispatching).

Comment: You wouldnt know anything about this would you. `<class 'gluon.contrib.pymysql.err.InternalError'> (1050, u"Table 'plugin_ckeditor_upload' already exists")`

Comment: Are you working with an existing database? If so, then you may want to turn off migrations. Otherwise, you may need to run a request with fake_migrate so the web2py metadata files are made consistent with the existing table models -- that way it will know about existing tables and won't try to re-create them.